# Allocate memory for a struct in a function

Tags: c, memory, struct

I need to make an adfgx machine ([Code language from WWII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADFGVX_cipher)) for a project in school. But I am running into some problems.

There is a struct along with some functions defined in adfgx.h which looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
   char* alphabet;         
   char* symbols;          
   char* dictionary;       
   char* transposition;    
} adfgx;
```

In adfgx.c we include the header and I have to write a function that allocates memory for this struct with a predefined signature:

```
/* Creates a new ADFGX machine */
adfgx* create_adfgx(const char* alphabet, const char* symbols, const char* dictionary, const char* transposition);
```

So what I am supposed to do here is allocate memory for the struct in that function. I don't get how I am supposed to do this, because I don't now the size of alphabet, symbols, dictionary and transposition, so how can I now hom much memory I need to allocate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't now the size of alphabet, symbols, dictionary and transposition

Since the size is not passed in, the API must assume that `const char*` parameters represent C strings. This makes it possible to compute the desired size by calling `strlen`, and adding one to the result for the null terminator.

To avoid doing the same thing multiple times, I suggest defining your own function for string duplication:

```
static char *duplicate(const char *s) {
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(s)+1;
    ... // Call malloc, check results, make a copy
    return res;
}
```

Now you can use this function to populate the `struct`:

```
adfgx *res = malloc(sizeof(adfgx));
if (res == NULL) ...
res->alphabet = duplicate(alphabet);
...
return res;
```

Comment: Any particular reason to suggest writing your own variant of [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)
without mentioning that it is what you're suggesting?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is almost certainly a learning exercise, and writing their own version of `strdup` is probably its centerpiece. If professor wanted them to use `strdup`, OP would probably never asked this question :-)

Comment: One possible interpretation, yes.  It isn't the one that occurred to me, but it is far from impossible.  Another possible interpretation is that the function groups its arguments into a structure for convenience; the strings pointed at must last as long as code will be using the structure.  Then all that's needed is to copy the pointers into the allocated structure.  In that case, `strdup()` is not needed at all.  Still, on average, it is more likely that the strings must be duplicated, but I'm not sure whether `strdup()` is verboten.  I would have mentioned it -- these comments now suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `adfgx` does not depend on "the size of alphabet, symbols, dictionary and transposition" - it's the size of 4 pointers.

As to assigning values to `newAdfgx->alphabet` and other members, you can use `strdup`. Just be sure to `free()` the `strdup`ed strings when you free the instance of `adfgx`.